# how ListView in android Flutter works

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I've used Following Code to generate ListView in Flutter.

```
Widget listSection = new Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: new ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: _generateListItems().map((String value) {
            return _displayListItem(value);
          }).toList()),
    );

    List<String> _generateListItems() {
    List<String> listItems = new List<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      listItems.add('List Item ' + i.toString() + ' title and description');
    }
    return listItems;
  }

    Widget _displayListItem(String value) {
     return new Container (
     padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     color: new Color(0X9900CCCC),
    child: new Text(value),
    );
   }
```

but i don't understand that how it's this code actually worked, It'd be nice if anyone can explain following lines.

```
children: _generateListItems().map((String value) {
        return _displayListItem(value);
      }).toList()),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somehow like this:

`_generateListItems` itself creates a List with Strings in it and returns it.

The `map()` [class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html) executes the code under it for each element and returns a `_displayListItem`. Then those items are converted into a list which is probably a `List<Widget>` at the end. Which can be used as `children`.

Comment: what does this code mean         .map((String value) {
        return _displayListItem(value);
      }) , actually i did not understand .map and its argument

Comment: This processes the `_displayListItem(value);` for every key in the list of generateListItems and gives back a Widget. You should include the `_displayListItem` function in your code. Otherwise one can just guess.

Comment: Ok, so the displayListItem wraps the given String into a widget (a Container widget). Which can then be used to show in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
_generateListItems().map((String value) {
    return _displayListItem(value);
  }).toList()),
```

is `equivalent to`

```
List<String> listItems = _generateListItems();
List<Widget> widgetList = [];
for (int i=0; i<listItems.length; i++) {
    widgetList.add(_displayListItem(listItems[i]));
}

return widgetList;
```

`list.map((x) {})` iterates through every item in `list` and `toList()` converts the result into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply think of map method as a conversion. The Map method converts each element in A array into another data type to form B array.
So your map convert a String array to a Widget array.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the crux of the code:

```
children: _generateListItems().map((String value) {
    return _displayListItem(value);
  }).toList()),
```

`_generateListItems()` returns a list of strings. Each string from this list (This is the parameter that the `map` method takes.) is then passed to `map` which in turn calls the `displayListItem` method. The `displayListItem` method wraps each of these string values in a Widget and returns the same. All these widgets are then put together as a list and displayed in the list view.